# generating multiple on click event using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi i am trying to that a program that generate multiple click events with different ids  depending on n-term. where n for now is 4,but it does not loop

here is my code

```
        for (var i=1 ;i<= 4;i++){       
            $('#rl+i').click( function () {
                $("#div"+i).fadeIn();
                $("#outer").fadeOut();

            });
      }
```

my goal is to generate the below output if it is possible

```
            $('#rl1').click( function () {
                $("#div2").fadeIn();
                $("#outer").fadeOut();

            });

            $('#rl2').click( function () {
                $("#div2").fadeIn();
                $("#outer").fadeOut();

            });
                $('#rl3').click( function () {
                $("#div3").fadeIn();
                $("#outer").fadeOut();

            });
                $('#rl4').click( function () {
                $("#div4").fadeIn();
                $("#outer").fadeOut();

            });
```

Comment: Actually you likely want `$('.rl').on("click",function () {
                var idx=this.id.replace('rl','');
                $("#div"+idx).fadeIn();
                $("#outer").fadeOut();
            });`
      and give your rl's the class of `rl`

Comment: this is working fine divs din't fadein/fadeout

Comment: I do not understand your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track. Just modify the selector in the for loop to be

```
$('#rl'+i).click( function () {....
```

So the complete for loop is

```
   for (var i=1 ;i<= 4;i++){       
            $('#rl'+i).click( function () {
                $("#div"+i).fadeIn();
                $("#outer").fadeOut();

            });
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
    $('#rl' + i ).click(function() {
        $("#div" + i).fadeIn();
        $("#outer").fadeOut();
    });
}
```